# Error running a J2ME program using Sun or Sprint wireless toolkits

Tags: java-me, java-wireless-toolkit

Have any of you used sun wireless toolkit or sprint wireless toolkit together with J2ME?

I get the following errors trying to run my J2ME app using either of them:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\WTK2.5.2\bin\sublime.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\SPRINT_WTK_332\bin\sublime.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
```

First of all, My processor is not an AMD 64-bit, its Intel Core 2 and
i'm using windows 7 64 bit. Does this make a diff? should i resort back to win 32 bit? 32 bit cannot run on 64 bit?! Whats wrong? How to fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I recently have the same problem, and I solve it installing JDK for 32 bits, reinstalling WTK and redirecting to the 32bits JDK version in the middle of installation.

At least, that work fine on my machine: intel core i3 64bits, win7 home premium 64 bits